# Linq search from comma separated string to double

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

Using MVC. In my form I have a textbox where user will enter item codes in this manner
100,101,102.

The basically I need to query the table.

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchItemcode))
{

    var itemList = searchItemcode.Split(',').Select(p => p.Trim());
    priceHistory = priceHistory.Where(s => itemList.Contains(s.ITEM_CODE));
}
```

but in the DB, my field is double and this is not working. I was thinking may be to create a list ? then use that in my linq?

Comment: So `.Select(p => double.Parse(p))` before you `.Where` it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchItemcode))
{
    var itemList = searchItemcode.Split(',').Select(p => double.Parse(p.Trim()));
    priceHistory = priceHistory.Where(s => itemList.Contains(s.ITEM_CODE));
}
```

It should give you doubles.

Comment: thanks but I'm still getting the same error underlined under itemList.Contains. the error is:
cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<double>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<double?>. I also tried Where(s => itemList.Contains((double) s.ITEM_CODE)); but this only will give me the result for one item.

Comment: you have a nullable double, not double in your type. You can cast it to nullable like : `i.Select (x => (double?)double.Parse(x.ToString()))` . You could also call the `.AsQueryable() ` on that if you need an IQueryable ...

Comment: If you don't want to generate exceptions if the string is not actually a double, you can use `Select(p => {double value; double.TryParse(p.Trim(), out value); return value;})`

Comment: @MattKo +1. Never trust user input ... ever ... But, for simplicity's sake, the above answer shows him/her the path. You could have also added a select where type = int, and then the parsing would be ok as well ...